# Showing multiple values of an object in a Django ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, menu

I have a form that queries my database like so:

```
class Pull(forms.Form):
    select = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=OrderEntry.objects.values_list
    ('val_a', 'val_b'), required=True)
```

By default, it will show the values, but it's really ugly and not fun to look at. On the webpage it looks something like this in the drop-down menu:

```
('A','B')
('C','D')
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
A    |    B
C    |    D
```

Or really, anyway that would be easy for a user to read. Is there a way I can achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass ModelChoiceField and define `label_from_instance` to return the value you want.

```
class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "{} | {}".format(obj.val_a, obj.val_b)
```

Now use that with a standard queryset:

```
select = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=OrderEntry.objects.all(), required=True)
```

Comment: Great and quick response, thanks! I'g getting some syntax errors when I try to make the subclass. `ModelChoiceField is not defined`.

Comment: Sorry, updated to use the `forms` reference for consistency.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I will select this as the answer! I have a bonus question if you're up for it. How do I evenly space all the objects out?